# Have an issue with message not being defined - Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord

I am having difficulties with a Discord bot I am trying to make. I have made progress on the bot actually functioning and is added to the server, but i'm having problems with it actually working how I want it to.

I keep getting this error:

```
if (message.content.includes("i'm home")) {message.channel.send(message = "Welcome home!");}
^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rick\Documents\CiscoBot\mybot.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

I don't exactly get what's wrong, especially when my code (in it's entirety) is considered:

```
let Discord = require ("discord.js");

let client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", function(message) { let input = message.content()})
{
if (message.content.includes("i'm home")) {message.channel.send(message = "Welcome home!");}
}
{
if (message.content.includes("can we talk")) {message.channel.send(message = "Of course, what's the matter?");}
}
{
if (message.content.includes("that's it")) {message.channel.send(message = "Sorry to hear. Tomorrow is a new day!");}
}
{
if (message.content.includes("i need a hug")) {message.channel.send(message = "Gladly! [Hugs] :3");}
}
{
if (message.content.includes("whisper dirty things to me")) {message.channel.send(message = "[Whispers] The dishes are nasty. Clean them.");}
}
{
if (message.content.includes("i'm leaving now")) {message.channel.send(message = "Okay! See you later! :heart:");}
};
client.login("My App Token");
```

How should I fix this? I am extremely new to this and really want to make this bot. I'm determined to have it finished after spending a bit on it. It's intention is to respond when it detects certain words with it's own phrases. I've already fixed the syntax errors i'm aware of, it's just the "message is not defined" that's the problem for now.

Comment: you've not defined the message variable, inside the call of `message.channel.send()`. Try to change it to `message.channel.send("Your text here")`

Answer (score 0):

You should put you IF statements in callback of client.message function.

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
  if (message.content.includes('i\'m home')) {
    message.channel.send(message = 'Welcome home!');
  }

  if (message.content.includes('can we talk')) {
    message.channel.send(message = 'Of course, what\'s the matter?');
  }

  if (message.content.includes('that\'s it')) {
    message.channel.send(message = 'Sorry to hear. Tomorrow is a new day!');
  }

  if (message.content.includes('i need a hug')) {
    message.channel.send(message = 'Gladly! [Hugs] :3');
  }

  if (message.content.includes('whisper dirty things to me')) {
    message.channel.send(message = '[Whispers] The dishes are nasty. Clean them.');
  }

  if (message.content.includes('i\'m leaving now')) {
    message.channel.send(message = 'Okay! See you later! :heart:');
  }
});
client.login("My App Token");
```

Comment: your variable input is unuseful

Comment: it's not mine:) - author's:)

Comment: Thank you simpleDmitry! I'm not having any errors pop up now and the message not being defined seems to have gone away. For now, it seems like it will be working. Again, thanks for help!